# Convert utc time string to unix timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have string like this `2019-06-13 23:37:02.284175`.
I would like to convert this string to unix time epoch.
How can I convert this string to unix timestamp using python??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.7+ you can [do this](https://tio.run/##Pcs5DoAgEEDRnlMQKyggLO63IVEixTAEpvH0GAvt/it@uenC7HtPULASPwKdlOBkrNSUSXzWf8SKkBpGrBBIDM7YTZlZWc@d3/2yG6fdOtplGqR@h0YBipCy9wc) using [`datetime.datetime.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat):

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2019-06-13 23:37:02.284175").timestamp())
```

Output:

```
1560469022.284175
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
from datetime import datetime

string_date = '2019-06-13 23:37:02.284175'
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
epoch_time = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
print((datetime.strptime(string_date, date_format) - epoch_time).total_seconds())
# 1560469022.284175
```